# How to display a plain map with no geographic visualizations?

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to style a google map such that it will not display any geographic terrain visualizations?

When I say geographic visualizations, I mean those green/brown colors that emphasize the terrain height, and those shades that emphasize mountains. I just want a plain map with only borders between countries.
Is it possible? I couldn't find anything about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those green/brown colors are in the geometry element of the landscape feature. Here is the JSON to style your map.

```
[
    {
        "featureType": "landscape",
        "stylers": [
          { "visibility": "off" }
        ]
    }
]
```